# Creating a dynamic hierarchical array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this general data structure:

```
$levels = array('country', 'state', 'city', 'location');
```

I have data that looks like this:

```
$locations = array(
  1 => array('country'=>'USA', 'state'=>'New York', 'city'=>'NYC', 'location'=>'Central Park', 'count'=>123),
  2 => array('country'=>'Germany', ... )
);
```

I want to create hierarchical arrays such as

```
$hierarchy = array(
  'USA' => array(
    'New York' => array(
      'NYC' => array(
        'Central Park' => 123,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'Germany' => array(...),
);
```

Generally I would just create it like this:

```
$final = array();
foreach ($locations as $L) {
    $final[$L['country']][$L['state']][$L['city']][$L['location']] = $L['count'];
}
```

However, it turns out that the initial array $levels is dynamic and can change in values and length So I cannot hard-code the levels into that last line, and I do not know how many elements there are. So the $levels array might look like this:

```
$levels = array('country', 'state');
```

Or

```
$levels = array('country', 'state', 'location');
```

The values will always exist in the data to be processed, but there might be more elements in the processed data than in the levels array. I want the final array to only contain the values that are in the $levels array, no matter what additional values are in the original data.

How can I use the array $levels as a guidance to dynamically create the $final array?

I thought I could just build the string `$final[$L['country']][$L['state']][$L['city']][$L['location']]` with implode() and then run eval() on it, but is there are a better way?

Comment: So are you saying that some members of the array `$levels` may not exist? Like for example, a `$L['location']` might not exist?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, let me clarify above.

Comment: I'm still working on this @uncovery.

Comment: @FrankerZ Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my implementation. You can try it out [here](https://3v4l.org/n7vYW):

```
$locations = array(
  1 => array('country'=>'USA', 'state'=>'New York', 'city'=>'NYC', 'location'=>'Central Park', 'count'=>123),
  2 => array('country'=>'Germany', 'state'=>'Blah', 'city'=>'NY', 'location'=>'Testing', 'count'=>54),
);

$hierarchy = array();

$levels = array_reverse(
    array('country', 'state', 'city', 'location')
);

$lastLevel = 'count';


foreach ( $locations as $L )
{
    $array = $L[$lastLevel];

    foreach ( $levels as $level )
    {
        $array = array($L[$level] => $array);
    }

    $hierarchy = array_merge_recursive($hierarchy, $array);
}

print_r($hierarchy);
```

Comment: Is this the expected result? If not, please clarify, and I can attempt some other solutions =)

Comment: Yes that works perfectly, very smart idea to start from the back, did not think of that!

Comment: @uncovery be careful. This does not work if you have more than one entry from the same country. See here: https://3v4l.org/XUKKS .

Comment: You are correct @BeetleJuice. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @FrankerZ nice. Your solution is really clever. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @BeetleJuice Yours as well. (I've always tried to stray away from eval, as I've been told it causes performance hits, and can be dangerous), so I try to look for solutions that don't involve `eval()`. Regardless, your solution works, and is a viable alternative. Upvote for you good sir.

Comment: @FrankerZ `eval()` itself is not inherently bad; that's why it hasn't been removed from PHP unlike other functionalities.  However it is very dangerous if you're not sure what you're executing. In this case the code doesn't *do* anything, but build a data structure, and it only uses data from the application's database, a presumably trusted source. Thanks for the up. Reciprocated.

Comment: @uncovery & FrankerZ: another thing to note; the OP stated *"array $levels is dynamic and can change in values and length"*  This solution won't handle that variability

Comment: @BeetleJuice it seems to work for me though. Maybe we interpret the "Dynamic and can change in values and lenght" differently?

Comment: @uncovery what I mean is that the solution hardcodes `$levels` as the result of that `array_reverse()`.  So if `$levels` is set dynamically from, say a form input to `['country','state']`, this solution will not adapt to it.  You will need to also change the `array_reverse()` line or the result will always include all levels listed here.

Comment: @BeetleJuice ah yes I see what you mean, true, but very obvious and easy to fix :)

Comment: @uncovery Yes so it's not a big deal if you're aware of the limitation (hence my upvote). IMO it should be noted though because as-is the answer doesn't meet the spec.

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer, and I'll accept the changes. Not quite sure what you guys are intending on doing.

Answer (score 2):

Cool question.  A simple approach:

```
$output = []; //will hold what you want
foreach($locations as $loc){
    $str_to_eval='$output';
    for($i=0;$i<count($levels);$i++) $str_to_eval .= "[\$loc[\$levels[$i]]]";
    $str_to_eval .= "=\$loc['count'];";
    eval($str_to_eval); //will build the array for this location
}
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/1vFD8)

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought to do first, basically construct the new array as a string and then eval it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset always in fixed structure, you might just loop it

```
$data[] = [country=>usa, state=>ny, city=>...]

to
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $result[][$row[country]][$row[state]][$row[city]] = ...
}
```

In case your data is dynamic and the levels of nested array is also dynamic, then the following is an idea:

```
/* convert from [a, b, c, d, ...] to [a][b][...] = ... */

function nested_array($rows, $level = 1) {
    $data = array();
    $keys = array_slice(array_keys($rows[0]), 0, $level);
    foreach ($rows as $r) {
        $ref = &$data[$r[$keys[0]]];
        foreach ($keys as $j => $k) {
            if ($j) {
                $ref = &$ref[$r[$k]];
            }
            unset($r[$k]);
        }
        $ref = count($r) > 1 ? $r : reset($r);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
$locations = [
    ['country'=>'USA', 'state'=>'New York', 'city'=>'NYC', 'location'=>'Central Park', 'street'=>'7th Ave',  'count'=>123],
    ['country'=>'USA', 'state'=>'Maryland', 'city'=>'Baltimore', 'location'=>'Harbor', 'count'=>24],
    ['country'=>'USA', 'state'=>'Michigan', 'city'=>'Lansing', 'location'=>'Midtown', 'building'=>'H2B', 'count'=>7],
    ['country'=>'France', 'state'=>'Sud', 'city'=>'Marseille', 'location'=>'Centre Ville', 'count'=>12],
];

$nk = array();
foreach($locations as $l) {
    $jsonstr = json_encode($l);
    preg_match_all('/"[a-z]+?":/',$jsonstr,$e);

    $narr = array();
    foreach($e[0] as $k => $v) {
        if($k == 0 ) {
            $narr[] = '';
        } else {
            $narr[] = ":{";
        }        
    }
    $narr[count($e[0]) -1] = ":" ;
    $narr[] = "";
    $e[0][] = ",";

    $jsonstr = str_replace($e[0],$narr,$jsonstr).str_repeat("}",count($narr)-3);

    $nk [] = $ko =json_decode($jsonstr,TRUE);

}
print_r($nk);
```

Answer (score -1):

Database have three field:
here Name conatin contry state and city name

```
id,name,parentid
```

Pass the contry result to array to below function:

```
$data['contry']=$this->db->get('contry')->result_array();
$return['result']=$this->ordered_menu( $data['contry'],0);
echo "<pre>";
     print_r ($return['result']);
     echo "</pre>";


  Create Function as below:

function ordered_menu($array,$parent_id = 0)
    { 
        $temp_array = array();
        foreach($array as $element)
        {
            if($element['parent_id']==$parent_id)
            {
                $element['subs'] = $this->ordered_menu($array,$element['id']);
                $temp_array[] = $element;
            }
        }
        return $temp_array;
    }
```